# Creating a Web frontend for Android App using android APIs.

Tags: php, android, ruby-on-rails, json, api

Thank you in advance for answer the question.

Here is the scenario and I want some suggestion of guideline how I can proceed.

I have an android app for Music streaming with following features

1. Music Streaming Ofcourse
2. Creating Playlists
3. user signin/signout
4. Search by category like album or artists or genre FM Radio Streaming
5. Push Notification
6. Equalizer and so on.

I also have a backend that is created in Ruby on Rail (Mysql database) for Music management like adding songs, genre, albums and artists. It also handles sending push notification and all.

And now I want to create a web frontend for users to enjoy the songs through their laptop or desktop so that I can give my users the flexibility to play songs, view playlist that they create in android devices.

Here is the main question:

How Can I create the frontend to use the json api that my android app is using so that I dont have to create another backend for the website.? Let me know if its possible or not.

If not possible to use the json api then how can I proceed so that I avoid another backend work?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Pass the json string to  the web service as a URL parameter.