# How secure is it to connect to a MySQL database from an Android app?

Tags: php, android, mysql, security

I am working on an Android app that deals with some slightly sensitive information (Names, Usernames, Passwords, Badge number, etc)... As far as code work goes, I know how to connect to a MySQL database with PHP and pull information from it via JSON.  I am just worried about the security of doing this.  I know there are plenty of Android and iPhone apps that currently implement login systems, but I was curious as to how secure those logins are.

Does anyone know where I can find some information on creating a secure connection to a database with PHP and MySQL for my login system through an Android app?  I know nothing is completely impenetrable, but I want to make sure the security of my app is as tight as possible.

As always, I am still getting used to StackOverflow, so if I was not clear or this question has already been answered, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

It is incredibly insecure to connect to a remote db from an app. Think of it like connecting to a database from javascript in your browser, because it is the same level of security.

As an important aside,

> slightly sensitive information (Names, Usernames, **Passwords**, Badge number, etc).

Passwords are not slightly sensitive, they are critically sensitive. I'm not sure if you are implying that passwords are being stored in a reversible format, but [they should be hashed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Anyway, to your main question, instead of connecting directly to a database from the client-side device, you will want to create an API that provides limited access. You would write this in the form of a web service, using some server-side programming. From there, you'll simply use an API key/roles based on the current logged in user. This is the secure/proper way to design this system. You do not want to put db credentials in an app, unless they are for a local db on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're rolling your own authentication code, it's really hard to say how secure it is. Often people get this horribly wrong and the code has the opposite effect: Instead of securing the site it exposes several severe holes that can be used to hijack it and download arbitrary data.

A [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in. If there's vulnerabilities in that code, which is reviewed by the community, there's usually an advisory posted so you'll know and can patch as necessary.

If you follow best practices, you should be fine. JSON via PHP or any other language is a good way to go if you want to keep things simple and secure.

Answer (score 1):

Its really hard to gain 100% , but you can use some techniques like

1. SSL
2. Session for each user
3. something like verification code sent through SMS
4. Encryption data before sent over API calls etc

Answer (score 1):

To extend what Gray said, you can pass the JSON data through the URL that you're shipping to the web service that's providing the front end to your DB.  There are a couple of other examples [that you can find here to start.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128979/creating-a-web-frontend-for-android-app-using-android-apis) As pointed out, it's a really bad idea to have direct DB access.  Even with a front end, you'll want to ensure that you're doing lots of data checking in the front end.  Don't pass direct SQL queries!  They're too easy to hack. SQL injection continues to be one of the most successful attacker techniques.

You might consider a Mobile Backend as a Service provider, like Kii, Kumulos, Kinvey, Kony (not sure why they all start with K...), or built.io. They'll cost you money, but save you headaches.